# How do I combine 2 columns to show data from both columns into single column?

Tags: sql-server

How do I show the data of 2 columns into single column ? 
Here is the example :

```
Column 1   Column 2
```

Result:

```
Column 1
Column 2
```

Comment: Look at the UNION keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VALUES` to unpivot your data:

```
SELECT V.[Column]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Column1),(Column2))V([Column]);
```

This **assumes** `Column1` and `Column2` have the same data type.